# Use calculated field value in other field SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I whould like to use the value from one field in another field of the same query

This is a fragment of my query

```
SELECT
    ...
    ...
    ISNULL(
        FORMAT(reg.FechaFin,'yyyy/MM/dd'),
        ISNULL(
            DATEADD(YEAR, 1, FORMAT(reg.FechaInicio,'yyyy/MM/dd')),
            ISNULL(
                DATEADD(YEAR, 2, FORMAT(reg.FechaCreacion,'yyyy/MM/dd')),
                ''
            )
        )
    ) AS "Estimated Engagement End Date",
    ...
    ...
    IIF(EEED is null, '',
            CONCAT('FY',
                IIF(IIF(
                    FORMAT(EEED,'MM')<6,
                    FORMAT(EEED,'yy'),
                    FORMAT(EEED,'yy')+1)
                        <10,
                        '0', ''),
                IIF(FORMAT(EEED,'MM')<6,
                    FORMAT(EEED,'yy'),
                    FORMAT(EEED,'yy')+1)
        )) AS "Close Date FY",
```

I want to use the value obtained in `"Estimated Engagement End Date"` to use it below in every place where `"EEED"` appears.

I don't want to copy and paste the same code every time because the query would look very messy (more than already is).

Is there a way to store temporally the value for each row in the table?

Comment: Use a derived table or a CTE, or you could put the expression within a `VALUES` table construct wuithin the `FROM`. Otherwise you need to repeat the *entire* expression.

Comment: Oh, and FORMAT will kill the hell out of your performance in the query ;-) Perhaps you should let the GUI decide how to display it

Comment: I didn't knew about CTEs, thanks, it helped me.
Also, I need to format the dates to the American one, my PC detects my location and formats it to other I don't want

Comment: You should also consider using a standard CASE expression instead of stacked IIF functions.  If your fiscal year starts on 7/1 of any given year then the FY would be current year + 1 for any months >= 7.  For that calculation all you need is: DATEPART(month, {month}) >= 7.

Comment: Stacking ISNULL can also be replaced with COALESCE and be much cleaner.  It is also quite useless to convert a date to a string format - and then use DATEADD on the formatted string.  That can easily be converted to: COALESCE(reg.FechaFin, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, reg.FechaInicio), DATEADD(YEAR, 2, reg.FechaCreacion), '').